# AD FS Add-Computer fails intermittently

Tags: powershell, adfs, domaincontroller

I'm attempting to use Powershell to script the configuration of an AD FS server.  I'm new to Powershell, and AD.  My goal is a reliable automated process.

I use this command to attach my AD FS server to my single domain controller:

```
Add-Computer "example.com" -Credential $credentialObject -NewName "adfsserver" -restart
```

... where the $credentialObject is created earlier in the script.

The problem: sometimes this command works, sometimes it fails with "Domain Controller not ready" error.  The last time I had such a failure was an hour ago at 16:27:03, I checked my domain controller and it was running happily and uneventfully at that time.  I tore everything down and re-ran the same scripts - no errors.  The error behavior appears indeterminate.

Question:  Is there a command I can use to see if a Domain Controller is ready?  Or is there a way I can have the Add-Computer command wait / retry a few times before failing?  I don't mind a temporary delay in a script, but I can't have a complete failure due to random behavior.

Comment: If its throwing you can definitely add a `$counter` in your `catch {...}` block

Comment: There's always something like `Do{$Attempts++;Add-ADComputer @Params}While(!$? -and $Attempts -lt 5)` that'll try and add the computer either until it succeeds or it tries and fails 5 times. `$?` tells if the last command was successful, and `!` inverts it, so that `While` clause says to do it while the last command was not successful, and `$Attempts` is less than 5.

Comment: One other idea is to join using a pre-created computer account. This will ensure the join is always reliable. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd392267(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN . But it does mean you will need to dig deeper into why your seemingly healthy domain controller was not contactable or otherwise usable when you tried to via PowerShell. Reviewing netlogon.log on AD FS member that you attempted to join domain is worth doing.